# Silverlight Datagrid to Excel export with cell formatting

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, excel, datagrid

Is there a way to do this in browser? (no AutomationFactory)

I know that I can export as CSV fine but I want to export my Silverlight datagrid as a Excel (.xls) document with the background colors of some rows set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with MS Excel using Silverlight CLR - it is the only way to use AutomationFactory (becouse of silverlight pesmission restrictions). Ms Excel should be installed on client machines.
But you can also pass data to web-service, process it, and return excel sheet as byte array.

I suggest you use the second way.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on how to do this second method?

Comment: i don`t know any tutorials about this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide which is pretty much what I needed, although it is not elegant. Basically, loop through and print all the rows into XML format. I find it very strange that Microsoft would not provide an in-browser method to export to an Excel format and we need to do stuff like this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45731/Export-Silverlight-DataGrid-to-Excel-XML-CSV

Answer (score 0):

Export grid from silverlight to excel mht will work for any colors and formattings.